# Get the row values first (moving the null values to the last of its row)

Tags: python, dataframe, data-mining, apriori

I'm working on dataframes, I need to get the row values first (moving the null values to the last of its row).

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset_two.csv',header=None) 
print(df.head())
print("___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___")
```

**output of the dataset**

```
0  Juice  Nachos   Tortilla   Cheese  Eggs  Banana  Milk  Bread  Butter

1  Juice     NaN   Tortilla   Cheese  Eggs     NaN  Milk    NaN  Butter

2    NaN     NaN   Tortilla  Cheese   Eggs     NaN   NaN  Bread  Butter

3    NaN  Nachos        NaN      NaN   NaN  Banana  Milk  Bread     NaN

4  Juice  Nachos  Tortilla   Cheese   Eggs  Banana  Milk  Bread  Butter
___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
```

**My Required output:** (into another CSV file)

```
Juice,Nacho,Tortilla,Cheese,Eggs,Banana,Milk,Bread,Butter

Juice,Tortilla,Cheese,Eggs,Milk,Butter

Tortilla,Cheese,Eggs,Bread,Butter

Nacho,Banana,Milk,Bread

Juice,Nacho,Bread
```

Can anyone help with this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question by Include a snippet of the code, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute and fix your indentation. Would be great. Thanks